# Modify every data response in strapi

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, content-management-system, strapi

Im wondering what the best way to execute a function before the any data is returned from the api so that i can modify the data response.

I know that i could add the function to every single controller however this would mean repeating myself a lot of times. Policies seemed like the correct thing to do however these will execute before the controller is hit.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
module.exports = {
  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    ctx.resp... // altering the data this way at the moment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A policy can be made to execute after the controller function has been executed the code has to come after the await next() as shown below.

```
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  // Indicate to the server to go to
  // the next policy or to the controller's action.
  await next();

  // The code below will be executed after the controller's action.
  if (ctx.status === 404) {
    ctx.body = 'We cannot find the resource.';
  }
};
```

kindly refer :[Advanced usage](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#policies)